# Effect of font size setting on Android webviews

Tags: android, android-webview

Android users can select a font size: [image: Android font size setting]

As a developer of a web-based app, I'd like to understand the effect of this setting on CSS properties in my app's screens. I've noticed that it affects the `font-size` CSS property. Does it affect anything else, or just `font-size`?